Godot & Dialogic 2 - How to add custom texture on dialog box
I’m new to Godot/Game Development and also to Dialogic 2. I need to add a custom texture (image) to a Visual Novel textbox, but I’m struggling with it.
I added a custom layer for the Visual Novel textbox and then added a TextureRect. However, it’s not sized correctly, and I’m not sure how to fix it. The texture should match the size of the black background, which comes from the DialogTextPanel. I also want it to resize as the Panel resizes, I really don't know how to achieve this.


Infos:

Using Godot 4.3
Using Dialogic 2 (not 1)

